# Shell Script - Unix - mailx

Tags: shell, unix, mailx

I'm having this problem when I send an email from Unix with the below 
commands   :

```
uuencode data.js.txt data.js.txt | mailx -r "From" -s "someSubject" "To@gmail.com"
```

So the issue here is when I receive the email , I don't get the attachment correctly .

I receive it like this :

```
begin 664 data.js.txt

M=F%R(%120E]0,3`@/2!;(C`T+3`W+3$V(#`X.C`P.C0T(S`C,",C(BPB,#0M
M,#<M,38@,#DZ,#`Z-3`C,",P(R,B+"(P-"TP-RTQ-B`Q,#HP,#HU-B,P(S`C
M(R(L(C`T+3`W+3$V(#$Q.C`P.C$P(S`C,",C(BPB,#0M,#<M,38@,3(Z,#`Z
M-3$C,",P(R,B+"(P-"TP-RTQ-B`Q,SHP,#HP-B,P(S`C(R(L(C`T+3`W+3$V
M(#$T.C`P.C$V(S`C,",C(BPB,#0M,#<M,38@,34Z,#`Z,S,C,",P(R,B+"(P
M-"TP-RTQ-B`Q-CHP,#HT,B,P(S`C(R(L(C`T+3`W+3$V(#$W.C`P.C4P(S`C
M,",C(BPB,#0M,#<M,38@,3@Z,#$Z,#`C,",P(R,B+"(P-"TP-RTQ-B`Q.3HP
M,#HQ,R,P(S`C(R(L(C`T+3`W+3$V(#(P.C`P.C(P(S`C,",C(BPB,#0M,#<M
```

When I send the file like this :

```
uuencode ${filename} ${filename} | mailx -r $FROM -m $TO
```

I will have no problems with the file , but i need a **subject** in my mail .

What can I do :( ?

Comment: Try `( echo "Subject: hello"; echo; uuencode ... ) | mailx -r $FROM -m $TO`. Also, `man mailx` says that you can set the subject with the `-s` command line parameter.

Comment: See if your `mailx` supports `-A` or `-a` for sending attachments (if so, `mailx` does the encoding), or use another mail client to do it.

Comment: This inserts the Subject into the body

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending email in linux as subject and attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235505/sending-email-in-linux-as-subject-and-attachment)

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda  -a/A is not supported .

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found the solution :

```
(
cat << !
From : ${FROM}
To : ${TO}
Subject : ${SUBJ}
!
uuencode ${filename} ${filename}

) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f $FROM -v $TO
```

This option worked perfect .